# Deleting nested array entries in a DataFrame (JSON) on a condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I read in a DataFrame with a huge file holding on each line of it a JSON object as follows:

```
{
  "userId": "12345",
  "vars": {
    "test_group": "group1",
    "brand": "xband"
  },
  "modules": [
    {
      "id": "New"
    },
    {
      "id": "Default"
    },
    {
      "id": "BestValue"
    },
    {
      "id": "Rating"
    },
    {
      "id": "DeliveryMin"
    },
    {
      "id": "Distance"
    }
  ]
}
```

How could I manipulate in such way the DataFrame, to keep only the module with *id="Default"* ? How to just delete all the other, if **id** does not equal **"Default"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you have `json` format given in question in each line as

```
{"userId":"12345","vars":{"test_group":"group1","brand":"xband"},"modules":[{"id":"New"},{"id":"Default"},{"id":"BestValue"},{"id":"Rating"},{"id":"DeliveryMin"},{"id":"Distance"}]}
{"userId":"12345","vars":{"test_group":"group1","brand":"xband"},"modules":[{"id":"New"},{"id":"Default"},{"id":"BestValue"},{"id":"Rating"},{"id":"DeliveryMin"},{"id":"Distance"}]}
```

If thats true then you can use `sqlContext`'s `json` api to read the `json` file to `dataframe` as below

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("path to json file")
```

which should give you `dataframe` as

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
|modules                                                             |userId|vars          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
|[[New], [Default], [BestValue], [Rating], [DeliveryMin], [Distance]]|12345 |[xband,group1]|
|[[New], [Default], [BestValue], [Rating], [DeliveryMin], [Distance]]|12345 |[xband,group1]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
```

and `schema` be

```
root
 |-- modules: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vars: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- test_group: string (nullable = true)
```

Final step would be to `filter` only the `modules.id` with `Default` as value

```
val finaldf = df.withColumn("modules", explode($"modules.id"))
    .filter($"modules" === "Default")
```

which should give you

```
+-------+------+--------------+
|modules|userId|vars          |
+-------+------+--------------+
|Default|12345 |[xband,group1]|
|Default|12345 |[xband,group1]|
+-------+------+--------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

this would create `json` as

```
{"modules":"Default","userId":"12345","vars":{"brand":"xband","test_group":"group1"}}
{"modules":"Default","userId":"12345","vars":{"brand":"xband","test_group":"group1"}}
```

But if your requirement is to get as below

```
{"modules":{"id":"Default"},"userId":"12345","vars":{"brand":"xband","test_group":"group1"}}
{"modules":{"id":"Default"},"userId":"12345","vars":{"brand":"xband","test_group":"group1"}}
```

You should be *exploding* the `modules` and not `modules.id`

```
val finaldf = df.withColumn("modules", explode($"modules"))
    .filter($"modules.id" === "Default")
```

Comment: This is close to the solution, but unfortunately, if I write the JSON file after this it will have "Default" as a simple String element inside the modules array. 
See:   
...
"modules": "Default",
...

I would like to keep it as a JSON element inside { } as

  "modules": {"id" : "Default"}              


I don't want to lose the structure/schema.

Comment: Upvote and accepted your answer.
Would you have a solution also without implicits inside the filter()? I mean don't use $ and ===

Comment: never mind the above. how should I pass in a List of Strings and filter on multiple modules? something like:
filter(validModules.contains($"modules.id"))

Comment: you should go with udf function for that :) Please ask another question for that as this answer is sufficient for the question. :)

Comment: define an array `val validModules = Array("Dfault", "default")` define a udf function `def contains = udf((list: mutable.WrappedArray[String], string: String) => list.contains(string))` and use the udf function in filter as `.filter(contains(lit(validModules), $"modules.id"))`.

Comment: thank you @Ramesh Maharjan! unfortunately this keeps only one from the validModules array in modules array in the result. it does not keep all of them. so if you would run this with validModules = Array("Default", "New", "BestValue"), then each line would hold only 1 modules instead having an array of them. I would ask a separate question

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391632/filtering-out-nested-array-entries-in-a-dataframe-json-by-passing-in-a-list-of

Comment: Answered it :) please check