# Filtering out nested array entries in a DataFrame (JSON) by passing in a list of values to match against

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I read in a DataFrame with a huge file holding on each line of it a JSON object as follows:

```
{
  "userId": "12345",
  "vars": {
    "test_group": "group1",
    "brand": "xband"
  },
  "modules": [
    {
      "id": "New"
    },
    {
      "id": "Default"
    },
    {
      "id": "BestValue"
    },
    {
      "id": "Rating"
    },
    {
      "id": "DeliveryMin"
    },
    {
      "id": "Distance"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to pass in to a method a list of module id-s and clear out all items, which don't make part of that list of module id-s. It should remove all other modules, which's id is not equal to any of the values from the passed in list.

Would you have a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

As you know from [Deleting nested array entries in a DataFrame (JSON) on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336055/deleting-nested-array-entries-in-a-dataframe-json-on-a-condition/47343117?noredirect=1#comment81735833_47343117) the way of reading your `json` file and manipulation of `modules` column which has `schema` of

```
root
 |-- modules: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

which says that `modules` is a *collection* of `struct[String]`. For the current requirement you will have to convert the `Array[struct[String]]` to `Array[String]`

```
val finaldf = df.withColumn("modules", explode($"modules.id"))
                  .groupBy("userId", "vars").agg(collect_list("modules").as("modules"))
```

Next step would be define a `udf` function as

```
def contains = udf((list: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {
  val validModules = ??? //your array definition here for example : Array("Default", "BestValue")
  list.filter(validModules.contains(_))
})
```

And just call the `udf` function as

```
finaldf.withColumn("modules", contains($"modules")).show(false)
```

That should be it. I hope the answer is helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Ramesh! Almost there, but I want to have the modules not as an array of strings, but as a list of JSON objects e.g. {
      "id": "Default"
    }

Comment: secondly, why do I have to define all the columns that I want to keep in the groupBy() method? isn't there another way?

Comment: 3rd thing: validModules must be passed in as method parameters

Comment: @esbej, you have said in the question `**"I would like to pass in to a method a list of module id-s"**`, secondly I have used `"userId", "vars"` in groupBy in order to preserve the strings in array while using collect_list so that only the exploded strings get collected. for your third comment do you want variety of validModules to be passed as parameters? If so can you provide with some examples.